# I would like to know a mid/advance use of return on functions, I see it and I know how it works but not quite sure?

Tags: javascript, html, refactoring

I see some programmers that use the return reserved word to return a value or a function parameter/attribute, sometimes they use it to return a class constructor attribute and so on! ... The list is pretty long, this is why I need help with this.

I know the basic usage of this. No more.

```
const board = document.querySelector('#container');
const sideMenuBoard = document.querySelector('#top-menu');

var USER_ACCOUNT = localStorage.currentUser ? JSON.parse(localStorage.currentUser) : null; // I need to see if with getItem this will work

const routes = [
    {url: "dashboard", title: "Dashboard"},
    {url: "login",title: "Login"},
];

main.start = function(){
    if(USER_ACCOUNT != null){
        //board.style.display = sidemenuBoard.style.display = '';
        //sidemenu(sidemenuBoard);
    }
    main.set();
}

main.set = function(page){
    if(!USER_ACCOUNT){
        window.location.hash = 'login';
        page = 'login';
    }

    if (window.location.hash == '') {
        window.location.hash = 'dashboard';
    }

    if (!page) {
        page = window.location.hash;
    }

    let _page = window.location.hash.replace("#", "").split(/[\/\?]/)[0];


    if(USER_ACCOUNT && _page == "login"){
        window.location.hash = 'dashboard';
        return
    }

    let route = routes.find( r=> r.url == page) || {};
    //Let's call the pages dynamically

    page = _page[0].toUpperCase() + _page.substr(1);
    main.load(page, (Page) => {
        board.className = (route.class || route.url) || '';
        new Page(board);
    });
}

main.load = function (page, onload){
    if (!page) return '404';

    let _page = page.toLowerCase();
    let _class = _page[0].toUpperCase() + _page.substr(1) + 'Page'; //To uppercase and ignore the # simbol then add the name of the route and add the Page string to it

    try {
        new(Function('return ' + _class));
    } catch (err) { // Why this: It's because this give us the try, I know this give us the error 
        var _script = ox.script('', {}, document.createElement('div'));
        _script.src = './src/pages/' + _page + '.js';
        document.body.appendChild(_script);
        _script.onerror = () => {
            return '404';
        }

        _script.onload = () => {
            onload && onload(load(_class)); // Por qué && ? !*Para asignar como parámetro al metodo la variable class creada más arriba? 
        }
        return
    }

    onload && onload(load(_class));

    function load(_page) {
        let page = getClass(_page);
        return page;
    } 
} /* Todo este bloque es simplemente para generar la pagina correspondiente al hash y asignarle una clase con el nombre del hash obtenido. */

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    main.start();
});

window.onhashchange = (evt) => {
    ///TMP
    let page = window.location.hash;
    main.set(page);
}

function getClass(className) {
    return Function('return ' + className)();
}
```

Everything from this code works, and but I don't understand some things.

Comment: The `return` statement causes a call to a function to exit immediately and return to the point from which it was called. More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: "Everything from this code works, and but I don't understand some things." ... what things? Spell it out.